# Add consistent margin to paths aligned to circles in D3.js

Tags: javascript, math, d3.js, svg, drawing

I have [this graph I've made](https://jsfiddle.net/asbjornu/aqqem493/5/) with [D3.js](https://d3js.org/), which is basically just a few circles with paths between them. What I want is to reduce the path algorithm down to something that as terse and neatly as possible calculates the "margins" of the paths so they don't overlap the circles.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="graph"></div>
```

And here's the JavaScript:

```
var graph = d3.select('.graph')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', window.innerWidth)
    .attr('height', window.innerHeight);

var defs = graph.append('svg:defs');

var blueGradient = defs.append('svg:linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'b')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', 0)
    .attr('y2', 1)
    .attr('spreadMethod', 'pad');

blueGradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '0%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#e4f5fc')
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

blueGradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#2ab0ed')
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

var orangeGradient = defs.append('svg:linearGradient')
    .attr('id', 'o')
    .attr('x1', 0)
    .attr('y1', 0)
    .attr('x2', 0)
    .attr('y2', 1)
    .attr('spreadMethod', 'pad');

orangeGradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '0%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#f6e6b4')
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

orangeGradient.append('svg:stop')
    .attr('offset', '100%')
    .attr('stop-color', '#ed9017')
    .attr('stop-opacity', 1);

var head = defs.append('svg:marker')
    .attr('id', 'head')
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
    .attr('markerWidth', 2)
    .attr('markerHeight', 4)
    .attr('refX', 0.1)
    .attr('refY', 2);

head.append('path')
    .attr('d', 'M0,0 V4 L2,2 Z')
    .attr('fill', '#aaa');

var nodes = [{
        x: 200,
        y: 50,
        c: 'b',
    },
    {
        x: 400,
        y: 50,
        c: 'b'
    },
    {
        x: 600,
        y: 50,
        c: 'b'
    },
    {
        x: 725,
        y: 175,
        c: 'b'
    },
    {
        x: 600,
        y: 300,
        c: 'o'
    },
    {
        x: 400,
        y: 300,
        c: 'o'
    },
    {
        x: 200,
        y: 300,
        c: 'o'
    },
    {
        x: 75,
        y: 175,
        c: 'o'
    }
];

var lineData = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d.y;
    });

graph.selectAll('path.nodes')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', function(currentNode, i) {
        var nextNode = i < nodes.length - 1 ?
            nodes[i + 1] :
            nodes[0];

        startPath = {
            x: currentNode.x,
            y: currentNode.y,
            c: currentNode.c
        };

        endPath = {
            x: nextNode.x,
            y: nextNode.y,
            c: nextNode.c
        };

        var diff = {
            x: nextNode.x - currentNode.x,
            y: nextNode.y - currentNode.y
        };

        var margins = {
            current: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            },
            next: {
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            }
        };

        if (diff.x > 0) {
            margins.current.x = 20;
        } else if (diff.x < 0) {
            margins.current.x = -20;
        }

        if (diff.y > 0) {
            margins.current.y = 20;
        } else if (diff.y < 0) {
            margins.current.y = -20;
        }

        if (margins.current.x != 0) {
            margins.next.x = margins.current.x < 0 ?
                Math.abs(margins.current.x * 1.5) :
                margins.current.x * -1.5;
        }

        if (margins.current.y != 0) {
            margins.next.y = margins.current.y < 0 ?
                Math.abs(margins.current.y * 1.5) :
                margins.current.y * -1.5;
        }

        startPath.x += margins.current.x;
        startPath.y += margins.current.y;
        endPath.x += margins.next.x;
        endPath.y += margins.next.y;

        return lineData([startPath, endPath]);
    })
    .attr('stroke', '#aaa')
    .attr('stroke-width', 10)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#head)');

graph.selectAll('circle.nodes')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('svg:circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .attr('r', 19)
    .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return 'url(#' + d.c + ')';
    })
    .attr('stroke', function(d) {
        switch (d.c) {
            case 'b':
                return '#2E75B6';
            case 'o':
                return '#BF9000';
        }
    });
```

Can someone help me figure out why all my paths aren't neatly and consistently spaced from the circles? Shouldn't `20` units distance (the margin I'm adding through the `margins` object) mean the same regardless of what angle and direction a path meets a circle?

If there's anything else I can optimise in the code, please let me hear it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is a geometric one. The distance from one circle to another when they are at the same `y` position is **smaller** than the distance from one circle to another when they are not at the same `y` position. Remember that for a given square whose side is ***s*** the diagonal of that square is ***s√2***.

Thus, you can improve your `if` statements with another magic number:

```
if (diff.x > 0 && diff.y === 0) {
    margins.current.x = 30;
} else if (diff.x < 0 && diff.y === 0) {
    margins.current.x = -30;
} else if (diff.x > 0) {
    margins.current.x = 20;
} else if (diff.x < 0) {
    margins.current.x = -20;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z5g9mtr7/

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! But instead of the arbitrary `20` and `30` unit margins, is it possible to calculate the margin based on the angle of the path and the radius of the circle?

Comment: Yes, of course, I hate magic numbers... but this is worth a **new** question.

Comment: Okay, I've posted a new question regarding the margin calculation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44422735/61818